# rest interface to configure, spawn, monitor, stop long tasks java

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, task

I'm looking for suggestion about this project.
I would like to build a web ui from which configure, launch, monitor, long lived task (potentially weeks).
I was thinking of a mongodb database where to write configuration and a monitoring service from which detect change and eventually spawn new tasks.
However this solution has lots of issues and drawbacks:

- If a service died? how should I know, present part of the result (or the cuase of fail) to the user?
- If i want to monitor the service (i.e. how much data it is collecting) where shoud i write this info? (maybe i can write them to mongo)
- If i want to stop a service? I may write the stop condition to mongo (a boolean in the configuration document?)
  Do you know some example project? It can be considered a task list with a real running task behind it.
  Other info that could be related to the problem: I write usually in kotlin (coroutines look like a good alternative I need to study them thoroughly), I use Spring, Camel, and Kafka. I have an ELK stack where to put the message, I'm planning to write the UI with Vue.js (the web server is node.js at the moment). I don't want to use any cloud service. I'm alone on this project.

Comment: this question seems way too broad to me.  Too many questions...too open ended.

Comment: ...and what does being alone on a project have to do with using cloud services?  leveraging existing services is exactly what you should want to do if you're a single programmer rather than a team of 10.

Comment: @JoeAdmin, you are right about cloud service. I have edited my question; I cannot use them due to company policies. Is really the question that broad? I’m merely looking for suggestion and examples in order to build a WEB UI for spawning long task with  some of the mentioned technologies

Comment: Have you checked the JHipster (https://www.jhipster.tech/) ?
It is the perfect tool to bootstrap a new project especially "when you are alone" or you need something fast and the resources that you have are not enough.
Related to the scheduler have you considered the ScheduledExecutorService or the @Scheduled annotation ?